# Ruby app responding until stack goes too deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, routes, web-crawler, response

I'm at a loss here. I have a fairly simple thing going but seem to run into problems a lot with this. I have straight forward web crawler in the works. People post requests and send it on to the queue. If they want to query whats in the queue: the route is

127.0.0.1:8080/requests/id/1.json

response is the action (def)
CrawlerController is controller.
request is the model.

Heres the route: (although I don't think its relevant)

```
  match 'requests/id/:id' => 'crawler#response'
```

And here is the def within the controller:

```
  def response
    @request = Request.find(params[:id])
   respond_to do |format|
     #format.html { render :action => "new"}
     format.json { render :json => @request.to_json }
    end
  end
```

The error I'm getting is stack level too deep. If i look at the console output:

EDIT: lines 21 and 19 are the @respond to do and format.json

```
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "requests".* FROM "requests" WHERE "requests"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "requests".* FROM "requests" WHERE "requests"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "requests".* FROM "requests" WHERE "requests"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "requests".* FROM "requests" WHERE "requests"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "requests".* FROM "requests" WHERE "requests"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "requests".* FROM "requests" WHERE "requests"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "requests".* FROM "requests" WHERE "requests"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "requests".* FROM "requests" WHERE "requests"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "requests".* FROM "requests" WHERE "requests"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "requests".* FROM "requests" WHERE "requests"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2688ms

SystemStackError (stack level too deep):
  app/controllers/crawler_controller.rb:21:in `response'
  app/controllers/crawler_controller.rb:19:in `response'
  app/controllers/crawler_controller.rb:21:in `response'
  app/controllers/crawler_controller.rb:19:in `response'
  app/controllers/crawler_controller.rb:21:in `response'
  app/controllers/crawler_controller.rb:19:in `response'
```

pretty strange huh?

Comment: I swear if this turns out to be another missing end block *Shakes fist*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try renaming your method from `response` to something else. I think `response` might be used by Rails for something else.

Comment: its changed to uninitialized constant now. Gonna try work this out.

Comment: yep. thats what it was. I think

Answer (score 1):

Try renaming your variable from `@request` to something else.   I think `@request` might be used by Rails for something else.

Also try renaming your action from `response` to something else.   I think `response` might be used by Rails for something else.